# R foreach error unable to allocate size 34.6 GB when I have 140GB+ memory allocated to R

Tags: r, foreach

I am trying to use R's **doSNOW** and **foreach** packages to parallelize **ranger** random forest classification predictions on a file that is a little over 15MM records and 82 attributes.

I am using an AWS EC2 instance the size of m4.10xlarge. It is a Windows OS and R is 64-bit. I have definitely allocated over 100GB of RAM to R and I have cleared any garbage memory out. I only have a random forest ranger model and the 15MM record dataframe as objects in R, yet when I try run my code (regardless of the splits/chunks I try), I get errors similar to the following:

```
error calling combine function:
<simpleError: cannot allocate vector of size 34.6 Gb>
```

For each record, I'm predicting the class at each tree so I can later calculate class probabilities. I can run the prediction easily on the entire file, but it's too slow and I have a lot more files to predict on. All I'm trying to do is speed up the process, but no matter what I do, I keep getting this error. I have spent hours online looking for info, but cannot find anyone else with this issue.

Here is my prediction code:

```
num_splits <- 7
cl <- makeCluster(num_splits,outfile="cluster.txt")
registerDoSNOW(cl)

writeLines(c(""), "log.txt")

system.time(
 predictions<-foreach(d=isplitRows(df2, chunks=num_splits),
                   .combine = rbind, .packages=c("ranger")) %dopar% {
                     sink("log.txt", append=TRUE)
                    (predict(model1, data=d,predict.all=TRUE)$predictions)
                   })
stopCluster(cl)
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error and how to fix it? Is it possible I'm allocating too much memory to R and that's why?

Or could the way I'm combining the results be causing issues -- I'm trying to stack predictions from each chunk on top of each other so I have a row of tree level predictions for each of the 15MM records.

Thanks so much!

Comment: This means you ran out of memory. You will sometimes see an error similar to `<simpleError: cannot allocate vector of size 15 Mb>`.  It just means that there is not enough free memory for the next step of the process. One suggestion is to remove `.combine=rbind`. `foreach` will then return a list. You would have the opportunity to combine the result afterward.

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion -- I'll try it now. I just found it odd that I ran out of memory when I have so much allocated to R and my objects barely take any up, but it's possible trying to combine it all in one step is causing the issue.

Comment: Everytime `rbind` is called at least two copies must be made, this can be costly with large data and it is possible that each iteration may cause some fragmenting of the available memory, reducing the memory that would be useful in a following iteration. list items don't do the copying and allow R to store objects in different parts of the active memory (I not entirely sure of the second part of my statement, but I'm moderately confident it is right).

Comment: Thank you!!! You were 100% right and you saved me from having to pull an all-nighter! With 5 cores, I was able to run the code in like 10 minutes vs 50 minutes without parallelization. I don't think I would have ever figured that out about rbind on my own. So quick question, will the lists be in the order of my 15MM record dataset so I can just combine in order of the list?

Comment: Realized it was just rbind on the lists after the fact... So easy! Thanks again!